# Universal listener for JComponent

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jcomponent

Is there any universal listener for change value JComponent? 
I know only that reference is instance of JComponent and I want to add listener for changed values, e.g. when this component is a TextField and I change text.

Comment: *"Is there any universal listener for change value JComponent?"*  No, but then, we shouldn't best use a global listener in any case.  *"e.g. when this component is a TextField and I change text."* If by `TextField` you mean `JTextField` then for that one, look to a `DocumentListener` ..

Comment: yes there is only the EventHandler, rest is correctly descirber in comment by Andrew Thompson

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is No, there is no such listener. The closest solution to your case would be to try to use `PropertyChangeListener`.

Some details can be found here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html

But anyway, I think this is a X Y problem, so It would be better to describe problem and ask for solution insteed of asking for existatnce of some solution to unknown (to us) problem.

Comment: So "value" property in PropertyChangeListener will work for e.g. for JTextField ?

Comment: At the first glance, yes, but it depends on actual component implementation, if it is fireing property change events. This MAY be the closest solution to what you want, but only MAY, and may not. Again: There is not such universal listener, you would have to write it by yourself in form of some "spy" class that would attach to every possible event generated by given component and delegate event as needed.